# Extend assoc array

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to extend an assoc array.
The original array is like

```
$arr = [[
  'ID'      => 0,
  'TEXT'    => SOME_CONST,
  'CHECKED' => $opt_flag,
]];
```

With a new condition I would like to extend this existing array.

```
if (defined('MODULE_STATUS') && MODULE_STATUS == 'true') {
  $arr['JSON_ATTRDATA'] = 1;
}
```

The result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 0
            [TEXT] => text
            [CHECKED] => 1
        )

    [JSON_ATTRDATA] => 1
)
```

What is wrong that the new key is outside of the nestet array?

Comment: you want  $arr[0]['JSON_ATTRDATA'] = 1;

Comment: the array which contains the values is a sub-array of `$arr` at index 0, so you need to assign your new key to `$arr[0]['JSON_ATTRDATA']`

Comment: it is outside the nested array because you inserted it outside the nested array. if that is unclear to you, I strongly suggest to reread the PHP manual on how arrays work.

Comment: Why is the array nested in the first place? Do you really want a 2-dimensional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want  `$arr[0]['JSON_ATTRDATA'] = 1;` right now you appending to the parent array, you want the child array which has the key 0

Answer (score 0):

the Array `$arr` already having 1 object

to change this object value by its index

```
$arr[0] = "anything else"
```

and to add more objects

```
$arr[] = "Another object";
```

you should Call :

```
$arr[0]['JSON_ATTRDATA'] = 1;
```

will add another `key => value` to first object

Answer (score 0):

Do `$arr[0]['JSON_ATTRDATA']`

**DETAILS**

`$arr` contains array within array. Like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 0
            [TEXT] => text
            [CHECKED] => 1
        )
)
```

So when you add `$arr['JSON_ATTRDATA']` it add into first array